# Redirecting to different url using react-router

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have a project which has Signup/Signup page
By default, my project renders the sign up page, and has navigation to sign in, which redirects to /auth/sign-in/ path
My question is, how do i make the default sign up page redirect to /auth/sign-up instead of /? Because as per react-router documentation, there must be / as strict.
When i deployed my project to digitalocean and ran it with pm2, the path /auth/sign-in/ returns 404, but works on localhost, what could be the issue there?

My code for router.

```
 <Router>
<div>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Signin} />
  <Route path="/auth/sign-up" component={Signup} />

</div>
```

And my code for the nginx config for reverse proxy.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   root /var/www/myproject/build;
   server_name app.xx www.app.xx
   index index.html index.htm;
   location / {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the location value in your proxy to the directory that you want

or you can use the script `window.location.href = "/auth/sign-up";` conditionally just after your imports in App.js file but NOT in side the App class